# Sourcecontrol push is uploading all my projects, how do I only upload my current project?

Tags: xcode, git, push, commit

I set up git to my xCode a long time ago.

I've set up a new repository on github. And I want to upload ONLY the project I am currently working on. Whilst only having my desired project open, I go to source control and commit, however ALL my files show up - from other projects as well (not what I want). So when I do end up pushing, every single one of my projects which is present in the commit menu end up in the repository.

Is there a way I can simply just upload my current project and not have to include my other projects?

Thanks.

Comment: I don't know what your project structure is, but you can just make the root level of each project a Git repo.  Of course, if your projects share common  folders you will first have to detangle things.

Comment: Have you created 1 repository that holds all your projects? (it sounds like it)